# Adding project to build path - Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In Eclipse you have the option to add an existing project to the build path of another Java project. How can I achieve the same using Maven? (and Netbeans IDE)

Comment: Add the other project as a dependency...

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: suppose you add the other project to java build path -> projects